# What do the square brackets $[ ]$ and $\mid$ mean in $[G_t \mid S_t=s]$?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, math, notation

Here is the formula of state-value function in Reinforcement Learning.

[image]

What do the square brackets $[ ]$ and $\mid$ mean in $[G_t \mid S_t=s]$? Why use square brackets? Why use $\mid$?

Why do mathematical formulas use all kinds of ambiguous symbols? Not as unique as the symbols of programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets are part of the [**expectation**](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/expected-value) [operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)) (i.e. a function of a random variable, which in this case is $G_t$). This is common notation for the expectation. So, it's not $\left[ X \right]$, but rather $\mathbb{E}\left[ \cdot \right]$ or $\mathbb{E}\left[ X \right]$, for some random variable $X$. This notation is similar to the notation of a function $f(\cdot)$ or $f(x)$, but we use square brackets because expectations are taken with respect to random variables, which are actually functions (if this is too confusing, just ignore these details for now).

The $\mid$ is also common notation and means that we condition on knowing $S_t = s$ (an event). If you are not familiar with conditional expectations and probability distributions, you can take a look at them e.g. [here](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/conditional-expectation).

So, you can read your formula as

> the conditional expectation of $G_t$ (the return, i.e. the *sum of future rewards*), given that we know that the state at time $t$ is $s$ (i.e. the condition).

This is indeed the definition of the state value function.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I have a similar question. $\sum_{r}\sum_{s'}p(s',r|s,a)[r+\gamma V\pi(s')]$, the $p(..|..)$ is probability, what's the meaning of the follow square bracket part $[r+\gamma V\pi(s')]$? Is it means the $p(..|..)$ multiply by $[r+\gamma V\pi(s')]$?

Comment: I found that this is really a multiplication operation. This notation inconsistency confuses me very much.

Comment: @JoeHuang Yes. Sorry for not answering immediately. Here, $[ \cdot]$ would be like $( \cdot )$, so, yes, it's just a multiplication. They probably used square brackets because, if you turn this equation into an expectation, you will see that it will be equivalent to an expectation of a random variable that looks like what is inside the square brackets. See my blog post [here](https://nbro.gitlab.io/blogging/2022/02/16/bellman-equations/). It should clarify what I've just said.